# Java Eclipse running project gives message searching for main types

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run a project which a friend of mine send me, but I got a strange message which I've never seen before and not sure what to do to run the project without any errors. Here is what I got :

[image: eclipse project]

and I'm not really sure which one to choose so I can run the program. It's some kind of translator of C language.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of your friend?

Comment: Which of your classes has a `main` method?

Comment: actually the strangest thing is that none of the classes has main method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it could be one between `Parser` and `Scanner`, but you should type `org.aj.unitrans` in the search filter, so that only classes in that package are displayed.
If the filter finds no matches it means that there's no `public static void main(String[] args)` method in those packages, and they're probably to be used as a library by other programs.

Answer (score 0):

In Select type search window type your "class name" and then you will get a option like "class name- project name". Select and then click ok

Comment: Can you explane it a bit more? It's almost impossible to understand what you mean